# How can I have a Radio Group divided in 2 columns and 5 lines,containing 10 Radio Buttons?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, radio-button, radio-group

when I set the radio group to be horizontal, it only has space for 2 radio buttons, and when I set it to vertical I have space for as many as I want but only one per line. What I want to have is 2 radio buttons per line and 5 lines of them, all inside of the same radio group, how can I do this?

This is how I wanted it to be like:

[image]

Comment: and for which programming language you want to achieve this?

Comment: @rajat C# xamarin android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is a bit strange but it will work.

For view you will use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/Radio1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 4" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 5" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/Radio2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 6" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 7" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 8" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 9" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RADIO 10" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHECK"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private RadioGroup _rg1;
    private RadioGroup _rg2;
    private Button _btn;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _rg1 = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.Radio1);
        _rg2 = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.Radio2);
        _rg1.ClearCheck();
        _rg2.ClearCheck();
        _rg1.CheckedChange += OnRg1Change;
        _rg2.CheckedChange += OnRg2Change;

        _btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        _btn.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var check1 = _rg1.CheckedRadioButtonId;
            var check2 = _rg2.CheckedRadioButtonId;
            var realCheck = check1 == -1
                ? check2
                : check1;
            Toast.MakeText(this, realCheck.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        };
    }

    private void OnRg2Change(object sender, RadioGroup.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CheckedId == -1) return;

        _rg1.CheckedChange -= OnRg1Change;
        _rg1.ClearCheck();
        _rg1.CheckedChange += OnRg1Change;
    }

    private void OnRg1Change(object sender, RadioGroup.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CheckedId == -1) return;

        _rg2.CheckedChange -= OnRg2Change;
        _rg2.ClearCheck();
        _rg2.CheckedChange += OnRg2Change;
    }
}
```